# CSV data from PowerShell Export-Csv contains select clause on first line

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, select-object

I’m pushing data from `Get-ChildItem` to a csv, via some `Where-Object` and `Select-Object` directives as below.

The problem is that the first line of the csv contains the `Select` clause itself (eg literally `{ “This part” + $_.AndThisBit }`. Not sure why part of my code is leaking into the data?

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\Some\Path" -Recurse -Include *.msg, *.eml | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name.StartsWith("Confidential") -eq $false } |
    Select-Object { "Fixed-prefix*" + $_.FullName } |
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\another\path\Results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, avoid excessive piping. It would be much easier to debug the code if there are intermediate variables to inspect.

Comment: @vonPryz, for debugging this might be true, but not for a general rule of thumb for e.g. production scripts. Assigning a stream to a variable will choke the pipeline and could impact the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) doesn't take [ScriptBlocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-6), as `Where-Object` does. What you might want is:

```
Select-Object -Property @{Name="Prefix"; Expression={"Fixed-prefix*" + $_.FullName}}
```

To define a custom property with an *Expression*. That Expression is a ScriptBlock and gets evaluated.